# Salesforce | Get data from a field of an SObject record when i have only the field in string form

Tags: string, salesforce, apex

Lets say I have an SObject record

```
{
   Id: "abc",
   Field_A__c : "field A value",
   Field_B__c : "field B value"
}
```

and a string "Field_A__c".

In apex, is there anyway i can get the data "field A value" using just the record and the string?

if the field was not a string i could have done sobject.Field_A__c to get the value, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [get()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) method of **SObject** class.

The *get()* method takes String as argument and returns Object

Here is an example:

```
SObject sObjectObject = [SELECT Id
                         , Name
                         , Field_A__c 
                         FROM Account 
                         WHERE Field_A__c != NULL LIMIT 1];
String valueOfFieldC = (String)sObjectObject.get('Field_A__c');//Typecast Object to String
System.debug( 'valueOfFieldC=' + valueOfFieldC );
```